# ColorPaletteResources API in UWP app - How to set a ColorPaletteResources with own colors in App resources, by code and not only by Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, colors

I am developing an app that targets Win 10 1809 and and above.
I noticed that, starting just in 1809, there is a new API called `ColorPaletteResources` (it's a class inheriting from `ResourceDictionary`) that can be easily set in App.Xaml resources in order to customize app's color scheme, even the Accent color itself.

Now, if I use it like Microsoft Docs says, i.e. in XAML...

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->

            <ColorPaletteResources Accent="Yellow" AltHigh="BlueViolet" AltLow="Coral" AltMedium="DarkKhaki" AltMediumHigh="Aqua" AltMediumLow="DarkGreen" BaseHigh="Red" BaseLow="Gainsboro">

            </ColorPaletteResources>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other app resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

...it works great and it's really handsome (although in some control some visual state color still appears not customized: some pointer-over brushes still takes the system accent color... hope they'll fix it), and you can even specify one color palette for each app theme.
Another plus is that all these palettes don't interact with the High Contrast theme, so the app will have the exact behaviour the user expects when setting it's own colors in Settings.

**The problem is that this `ColorPaletteResources` doesn't seem to work when setting it in the code at run-time.**

I was really looking for a simple way to change all the app colors easily at run-time and I thought to finally have found that... but when I write this code in MainPage.xaml.cs...

```
        ColorPaletteResources palette = new ColorPaletteResources();
        palette.Accent = Colors.Red;

        App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(palette);
```

...nothing happens.

Questions for you:

1) Am I doing something wrong in defining the `ColorPaletteResources` in the code?

2) Is there a better way of changing Accent and all the main app colors (the ones with "SystemControl[...]Brush") without having to redefine all the templates and styles in the controls?

Thank you for your attention and your patience.

Best regards

EDIT: Regarding the use of this new API in XAML, I tried the Palette with all the color fields set. I just copied a earlier piece of code, so the problem that some pointer-over brushes still takes the System Accent color is real.

EDIT 2: I found that setting a `ColorPaletteResources` in app's resources via code works in the App.OnLaunched function and, in general, before the InitializeComponent func in every page.
How can I obtain the live cahnge for app colors, knowing this thing?

Comment: have you tried implement it on App.xaml.cs instead?

Comment: @Littledoe    Yes, I found that it works in the App.OnLaunched function and, in general, before the IniztializeComponent in any page.  But this isn't enough, as I wanted to change app colors in live.  Have to figure out how to use this thing that it works only at Page initializtion... any idea?

Comment: Please check the official code sample, you need re-set the [`RequestedTheme`](https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor/blob/master/FluentEditor/ControlPalette/ColorMapping.cs#L173) after add `ColorPaletteResources`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   Which code sample? I can't find it on GitHub.

Comment: Please check link [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   Thank you, but after some tries, I saw that in order to modify an app color at run-time with the ColorPaletteResources API, we have to set those colors first in the ColorPaletteResources XAML.  Can't we just start a ColorPaletteResources from scratch?

Comment: You could also set `ColorPaletteResources` with above code and refresh the theme like official code sample.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   By only code it doesn't work. May it be a bug? Could you test it?

Comment: Ok, I will test it, if it's bug, I will report it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   Thank you. By the way, it seems that this API can only modify the Accent color (and only the main one, not all the 6 other shades).  If you can check also that, it would be useful.  Best regards

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   Hi again, have you discovered something?

Comment: Not yet, and I have report this to related team.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   So it was effectively a bug, right? How are we going to know something from that team?

Comment: It is not yet confirmed that this is a bug. team has not replied info to us.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT   Ah, ok. I will be waiting for news here, in this question.  Thank you so much for your interest in this, since no one asked any question for this API before here on StackOverflow.